# Command supposed to delete author's message after the command is called but instead spams chat [discord.js]

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command where it's supposed to say something but then delete the author's message, but it instead spams the chat with the output and does not delete the message.

This is my current code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.content === "##@square")
      message.delete(100);
      message.channel.send("Gaming");
});
```

And this is the output I get: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0aQd.png)

Answer (score 2):

You have not checked to see if the user posting the message is the bot so when the bot posts "Gaming", the message event is fired **for that message**, creating a loop.

This issue can be fixed by ignoring all bots (recommended and [best practice](https://github.com/meew0/discord-bot-best-practices):

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return; // If the author is a bot, return.
    if (message.content === "##@square") message.delete(100);
    message.channel.send("Gaming");
});
```

... or by ignoring just your bot:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.id === client.user.id) return; // If the author's ID is the same as the bot's, return.
    if (message.content === "##@square") message.delete(100);
    message.channel.send("Gaming");
});
```

Although, it does seem like you've messed up your `if` statement: your current code will send "Gaming" every time a message is sent, no matter it's content. To fix this, put the code you want to run in curly brackets:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return; // If the author is a bot, return.
    if (message.content === "##@square") {
        message.delete(100);
        message.channel.send("Gaming");
    }
});
```

For more information on JavaScript `if` statements, see [this W3Schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp).